# MYSQL need log executed query in table along with executed user name

Tags: mysql-5.6, mysql-workbench, users, logs, monitoring

I would to like the executed quires with entire database tables for some mysql users only. Because some of users executed wrong query in production environment. And needs to store this log in new table. Is there any possible to do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is General log. There is Error log. Use them... [MySQL Server Logs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-logs.html)

Comment: thanks @Akina i would like monitor these process for particular users only, is there possible to do that?